# Nativescript html select box

Tags: xml, nativescript

I can't find anywhere how to make a select box in Nativescript's xml.  I have found dropdown menus, but I need a select box to look and feel just like a html select.

I've tried xml nodes, but didn't think that was the right place to be.  My end goal is to parse a JSON string out as the options in the select.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nativescript-checkbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-checkbox) plugin to create your custom selections.

Although this is a possible scenario, it is not entirely good practice to create HTML specific elements for the mobile world. More about how to adjust to the mobile world can be found in the design recommendations known as [Material Design for Android](https://material.io/guidelines/components/selection-controls.html) and [Human Interface Guidelines for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/).

Comment: Thank you for the links and the suggestions. I'll check them out.

Comment: Suggest any plugins present in nativescript work as HTML select-option.